# Creating a Blog ruby on Rails - Problem Deleting Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As I always type I am new to rails and programming in general so go easy. Thanks in advance.

I have successfully followed the initial tutorial from Ryan Bates on [how to build a weblog in 15 minutes](http://media.rubyonrails.org/video/rails_blog_2.mov). If you don't know this tutorial takes you through creating posts and allowing for comments on those post. It even introduces AJAX through the creating and displaying comments on the posts show.html.erb page. All works great.

Here's the hiccup, when Ryan takes you though this tutorial he clears out the comments_controller and only shows the code for creating comments. I am trying to add back the ability to edit and destroy comments. Can't seem to get it to work, keeps deleting the actual post not the comment (log shows that I keep sending DELETE request to PostsController). Here is my code:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 def create
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to @post }
     format.js
   end
 end

 def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(posts_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

/views/posts/show.html.erb

```
    <%= render :partial => @post %>

    <p>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path (@post) %> |
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', @post, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %> |
        <%= link_to 'See All Posts', posts_path %>
    </p> 

    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <div id="comments">
        <%= render :partial => @post.comments %>
    </div>

    <% remote_form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
        <p>
            <%= f.label :body, "New Comment" %><br/>
            <%= f.text_area :body %>
        </p>
        <p>

<%= f.submit "Add Comment" %></p>
<% end %>
```

/views/comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<% div_for comment do %>
    <p>
        <strong>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
        </strong><br/>
        <%= h(comment.body) %><br/>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', @comments, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :posts, :has_many => :comments
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Comment: "Can't see to get it to work" - what did you actually try to fix it?

Comment: I've tried changing the link_to in the comment.html.erb to @comment, comment, comments, etc. I also tried messing with the CommentsController destroy action by changing the @comment = Comment.find(params[:id]) to include @post.comment.destroy(params[:comment_id]).  A couple of others as well but it seems that either I don't have something in the routes.rb file done right or the link_to in the comments.html.erb is wrong. I'll update to include routes code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

meagar is on the right path, but since this is a nested route you have to do:

`<%= link_to 'Destroy', [@post, comment], ... %>`

So, you are passing the comment and the post and letting rails figure out the route based on your definitions.

Comment: thank you. Seems like I tried every combination but this. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In `_comments.html.erb`, change your `link_to` to

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', comment, ... %>
```

IE, pass it the `comment` itself, not the entire `@comments` array.

Comment: I get this error when I do that: undefined method `comment_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x10431fc68>